# Let $u,v$ be different vectors in linear space $V$ in $\Bbb R$ and let $S=\{u+v,u-v,u+3v\}$ then $Sp(S) \not = Sp\{u,v\}$ or..

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $u,v$ be different vectors in linear space $V$ in $\Bbb R$ and let $S=\{u+v,u-v,u+3v\}$ then
>
> 1.$Sp(S) \not = Sp\{u,v\}$
>
> 2. $S$ is a basis for $Sp(S)$
> 3. $Sp(S) = Sp \{u\} \oplus Sp\{v\}$
> 4. none of the above is true
>    (this is the correct answer , but why?)

---

In the textboox it says that number 4 is the correct answer , I tried approaching this way:

first checked linear independence

$$\alpha (u+v) + \beta (u-v) + \gamma (u+3v)=0$$

$$u(\alpha +\beta +\gamma) +v(\alpha - \beta +3 \gamma)=0$$

$$A= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1\\
  1&-1&3\\
\end{array}
\right)$$ $\qquad$after elementaryoperations $$A= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&2\\
  0&1&-1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
here I got confused a bit as if the general solution is : let $\gamma =t$ so $\alpha = -2t$ and $\beta =t$ so the general solution is $(\alpha , \beta , \gamma)=(-2t,t,t)$ from here the span of the set $S=\{u+v,u-v,u+3v\}$ is $Sp(S)=\{(-2,1,1)\}$ so option one is not right because $dimSp\{u,v\}=2$ and $dimSp(S)=1$

option 2 is not correct because S is not linearly independent so it cannot be basis for the $Sp(S)$

and 3rd option I do not know

Is my way correct? thanks for any help and tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did proves that the set $\{u+v,u-v,u+3v\}$ is linear dependent. But there was no need to do all that. This is a set of $3$ vectors taken from a space spanned by a set of less than $3$ vectors ($\{u,v\}$). So, they had to be linearly dependent.

You got right why the second option cannot be true. And the third option is false if, say, $u=v$.

Comment: thank you , just 2 questions please , by the last option with the direct sum , I just do a union to the spans and then I get that it is false ?
and for what I did for the first option , was it correct to write the span as $Sp(S)=\{(-2,1,1)\}$ just in general not related to the question itself is the span correct?

Comment: The third option is true in most cases, but it is false if $u$ and $v$ turn out to be linearly dependent, because then $\operatorname{Sp}(\{u\})\cap\operatorname{Sp}(\{v\})\ne\{0\}$. And it makes no sense to write that $\operatorname{Sp}(S)=\{(-2,1,1)\}$ because $(-2,1,1)$ doesn't have to be an element of $V$ and because $\operatorname{Sp}(S)$ is a vector space and therefore it cannot consist of a single vector.

Answer (score 1):

$Sp (S)=Sp (u,v)$: $u =(u+v)+(u-v)/2$ and $v =(u+v)-(u-v)/2$ so RHS is contained in LHS. I will let you check that LHS is contained in RHS. Thus, 1) is false.

3. Though $Sp (S)=Sp (u)+Sp (v)$ the sum on the right side need not be  a direct sum. Example: Take $v=2u$. So 3) need not be true.